# ANSI C stop process if user hits enter without entering data

Tags: c, scanf

my code is something like this:

```
double p, r = 12.40;

while (r > 0) {
   printf("\nEnter a amount $: ");
   scanf("%lf", &p);
   if(p == NULL) { break; }
   r -= (p / 100);
}
```

the `break` part doesn't work. I want to exit from `while` loop if user hits enter without typing any amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the loop to exit when the user presses enter, `scanf()` might not return control to your loop until the user enters a value (this is known as blocking).

You can use `fgets()` first, and then pass the input into `scanf()`'s relative, `sscanf()` to get that %lf double value.

As @EdHeal points out, scanf() has a return value that you need to check. It's going to return how many things it successfully converted, or a special value, EOF, meaning there's no more data to read.  This return value from `sscanf()` will let you know if the user entered a value or not.

So, putting it all together:

```
int main ()
{
    double p, r = 1240;
    char line[120];

    while (r > 0) {
        printf("\nEnter a amount $: ");

        fgets(line, 120, stdin); 
        int scanned = sscanf(line, "%lf", &p);

        if(scanned==0 || scanned==EOF) break;

        r -= (p *100);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For more information about `fgets()` and what each parameter is check out its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets%20%5Bman%20page%5D).

Comment: With this solution break works regardless if I enter a number or not. If I enter a number and hit enter it runs the `r -= (p * 100);` and then exits the loop. I don't want that. It is not the loop's condition. Loop should continue while r > 0

Comment: Since p is multiplied by 100, any value greater than 12 will exit since r is 1240 to start with.  I just picked up that line from your original post.

Comment: Oppps sorry. My bad. It should have been `r = 12.40;` and `r -= (p / 100)` (I have just fixed the main code in this post now)

Comment: So it exists the loop even if I enter 20

Comment: It might help you understand how the variables are all working if you print them out in the loop.  After the r-= line, try this: `printf("r=%lf p=%lf\n", r, p);`

Comment: Thanks Phillip. All good now. I was using `char line[4]` as I was just entering 3 digits. I changed it to `char line [5]` and all worked. So you were right with your code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's great, Ozgur!  I recommend that you make the size of line bigger than 5.  This is the buffer that will hold the entire line of input the user may enter.  It's OK if there's extra room in the buffer than you need.  But if there's not enough, it may not do what you want.  Try entering bigger numbers, like 500.999 in to see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

1. `p` is not a pointer but `NULL` equates to zero (usually). So this line is a bit pointless
   `if(p == NULL) { break; }`
2. Read the manual page for `scanf` - i.e. http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf. It does return a value that you need to check

Answer (score 0):

When the user presses enter here the `p` variable doesn't necessarily change to `NULL`. You should try getting a specific number or character for exiting the loop. Besides the `scanf` function waits until the user enters something, the program does not continue when you press enter without entering any values.